# How to remove glitch when navigating between Fragments with different toolbars?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I am using the Jetpack Navigation Component in an app with Single Activity structure.

Since in some Fragments the toolbar needs to be different or not be there at all, I am following [Google's suggestions](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#support_app_bar_variations), which basically says not to have the toolbar it in the Activity, but to move it in each fragment. So every Fragment (that needs a toolbar) has:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val navController = findNavController()
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)

    view.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
            .setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}
```

This will set up each `Toolbar` for use with a `NavController`. And the title in the Toolbar will automatically be updated when the destination changes (assuming there is a valid label).

Now, imagine we have two fragments:

- FragmentA: it has a toolbar
- FragmentB: it doesn't have any toolbar

When I am in FragmentA the toolbar with the title "Fragment A" is displayed. When I navigate to the FragmentB (through an Action) I would expect to have no toolbar. Unfortunally for a split second the toolbar will show "Fragment B".

I think the reason is that on FragmentA the toolbar is still "listening" to the changes happening in the navigation graph (it is basically tracking the current destination) and this result in updating its own toolbar.

NOTE: For this particular scenario I could remove the label from FragmentB, since we don t need any title because there is no toolbar. But there are still some scenario where this is a problem: for example if I in FragmentA I have a standard toolbar and in FragmentB I have a prominent header like the one in the image below, I would still see a glitch.

[image]

Does anybody have idea about how this could be fixed?

Comment: Why **are** you using labels in your navigation graph at all then? Toolbars have APIs to set a static title, which is certainly appropriate if you know that Toolbar is only associated with one fragment.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I thought it was a pretty convenient way for assigning the title in the toolbar. However removing the label would solve the problem of the title, but if fragmentB has not the back arrow, then it will appear for a split second. Is there a way for removing it?

Comment: @ianhanniballake unfortunately removing the label and using the title is not the solution, cause the glitch is still there. The only difference is that now in the FragmentB the title of the fragmentA appears.

Comment: So why is FragmentB not also using a static title for it's toolbar? It sounds if neither of those had a label, then you'd have perfectly static titles for both?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I removed all labels, so I am using just static titles in the toolbars (app:title="my title")